# Diophantine equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

There were 63 equal piles of plantain fruit put together and 7 single fruits. They were divided evenly among 23 travelers. What is the number in each pile. Consider the Diophantine equation 63x+7=23y

So I found one solution: -7= 6(-28)+23(7) 
so then I plugged it into the formula to find all solutions and got 
x=-28-23t and y=-28-6t

so then I got t<-1.2 and t<-4.7 but this range is huge.. where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you run the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://www.mathcelebrity.com/euclidalgo.php?num1t=63&num2t=%2023&pl=Euclids%20Extended%20Algorithm) on $63$ and $23$, you'll find that $63(-4)+23(11)=1$. This means that $63(-28)+23(77)=7$ and so $63(28)+7=23(77)$

This means that $63(28)+7=1771$ plantains were split among the $23$ travelers (each got $77$ fruits).

Where did you go wrong? I'm not sure. You didn't provide enough work to answer that. However, $6(-23)+23(7)=23 \not=7$. Next, your answer of a range "$t<-1.2$ and $t<-4.7$" just doesn't make sense. The given problem is clearly looking for an integer solution - not a range of real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

23y = 63x + 7 becomes 23y = 7(mod 63) which reduces to y = 14(mod 63).

So y = 14 + 63t. Substituting this y into the original equation you get

x = 5 + 23t. All possible answers are given by x = 5 + 23t and y = 14 + 63t.

If you use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm you get x = 28 + 23t and

y = 77 + 63t which is the same as above if you substute t = 1.